# How to reach a device on a different subnet?

Tags: subnet, route, access-point

I have what may seem to be a basic question about routing, but I ask it because I am not sure where to start.

I have a simple network setup:

Client1, Win7, 192.168.0.50, default gateway is set as 192.168.0.10
ISA 2006 firewall machine, Server2K3, 192.168.0.10 (South NIC), 192.168.1.10 (North NIC), North's gateway is 192.168.1.1
ADSL modem router, 192.168.1.1

I have now purchased a new Belkin WAP, so its default IP is 192.168.2.1. I've plugged it in, and tried to browse a web page to it, but I keep getting a server error 10060: Timeout.

The ISA server has a rule set up to allow all internal traffic to go to the WAP IP. While monitoring traffic going to the WAP IP the connection is opened but then times out with the above error.

Should I be adding a route to the ISA machine? If so, what should it look like? My intention is to simply log on to the administration page of the WAP and then change its IP to one on the 192.168.0 subnet, but at the moment I cannot seem to reach it at all.

Comment: You've not provided enough information for us to help, we'll need your various netmasks too please

Comment: @Chopper3, the netmasks are all 255.255.255.0. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution would be to use a computer to connect to the Access point directly with an ethernet cable.  Set IP on the computer to 192.168.2.10 ( for example)  and log on to the access point. Make your changes and save them.  Reset the IP on the computer and deploy the AP

Comment: Thanks Dave, this certainly worked for being able to connect and configure, but it would have been good to know if there was a route that could be set to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

WAP is a simple hub (not even a switch) and its IP is for administrative purpose only. Consider WAP as simple Ethernet patch, nothing more.

You should not to set up ISA in any special way, it won't need to route traffic to WAP IP.

Comment: And if you ask how to connect to web based control panel of WAP than better to set up the PC to use 192.168.2.x address, connect it to WAP directly (check to use right cable), and go to WAP IP with your browser (http or https - check the set up guide that comes with WAP). As you finish the setup, return PC to your network, and connect WAP to your LAN as any other Ethernet hub.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to wire directly to access point, the simplest solution is to just temporarily modify your workstation ip to be on the 192.168.2.x subnet.

ie:

ip: 192.168.2.100
subnetmask: 255.255.255.0

connect to wap with browser at 192.168.2.1 and change his ip to be on your standard subnet.

Now reconfigure your workstation back and you should be good