# Reach pc in the same network but a different subnet

Tags: networking, routing, subnet, ip-address, ipv4

PC 1 in subnet - 192.168.1.x
PC 2 in subnet - 192.168.2.x

Is it possible to access one pc from the other by its IP address without special router config?

related: [How to reach a device on a different subnet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/381104/how-to-reach-a-device-on-a-different-subnet)

Comment: It really depends what router configurations you consider "special". For example, if the same router is the default gateway for both networks, it should "just work". If the default gateway for each network knows how to reach the other network, again, it should work. But I don't know if just being configured to reach a network would be considered "special". I certainly wouldn't consider that special.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two different subnets are two separate broadcast domains. The only device that can traverse multiple broadcast domains is a L3-aware device (router, firewall, multilayer switch etc.).

You need a router. If you need a quick and dirty solution that is NOT AT ALL viable in the long term and for networks bigger than 2-3 pc, if they're really in the same L2 network (eg: two pcs connected on the same switch, with no VLANs configured), most modern Operating Systems allow you to configure multiple IPs for any given network card. That way you can give to Computer1 an address in Computer2's subnet and the two pcs are not really in two different subnets anymore :)

You. need. a. router.

Comment: Hi and thx. So manual ip configuration is needed that both ip addresses are in the same subnet, then they can reach each other? (Yes they are in the same layer-2 network)

Comment: Yes it would work. But this begs another, more important question, why do you have two subnets in the same L2 broadcast space? That's a big big big no-no.

Comment: I agree totally on that,  i was just thinking of in case that happens (on customers side).